# Error while passing parameter to javascript function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating list dynamically. When user click on that li element setCollege method will be called.

**Code to generate `li` is:**

```
$('#dropDown ul').append("
<li onclick=setCollege("+ data[i].id +",'"+ data[i].college_name +"')><i class='fa fa-university'></i>" + data[i].college_name + "</li>");
```

but javascript dynamically add `"` after space in college name like

```
<li onclick="setCollege(3,'Nirma" university')"> <i class="fa fa-university"></i>Nirma University</li>
```

due to `"`, it produces error while calling js function

Comment: Is `Nirma" university` the name?

Comment: `escape(data[i].college_name)`

Comment: `escape` does URL encoding, not HTML encoding. It's the obsolete name of `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: @Barmar, ok `encodeURIComponent(data[i].college_name)` then inside `setCollege()` the OP can just use `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: @Barmar and Reigel : No need to escape the `data[i].college_name`. It doesn't have any double quotes in between. See the resulted output value of `data[i].college_name` was `<li ......><i class="fa fa-university"></i>Nirma University</li><li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onclick is a html attribute, thus it needs to be put in quotes itself.

Try this instead:

```
var tpl = '<li onclick="setCollege(' + data[i].id + ', ' + data[i].college_name + ' );"><i class="fa fa-university"></i>' + data[i].college_name + '</li>';
$('#dropDown ul').append( tpl );
```

Pay attention to single vs. double quote usage.

But since your question is flagged as jquery, I'd suggest:

```
var listItem = $( '<li></li>' ).text( data[i].college_name );
$( '<i class="fa fa-university"></i>' ).prependTo( listItem );
listItem.on( 'click', function() {
    setCollege( data[i].id, data[i].college_name);
});
listItem.appendTo( '#dropDown ul' );
```

Comment: `.text()` will replace `<i class="fa fa-university"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't add the surrounding `"` to your onclick attribute:

```
$('#dropDown ul').append("
<li onclick=\"setCollege("+ data[i].id +",'"+ data[i].college_name +"')\"><i class='fa fa-university'></i>" + data[i].college_name + "</li>");
```

but why don't you use jQuery to attach the event to the list items? This would be the better solution:

```
$('#dropDown').on('click', 'li', function() {
    setCollege(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like:

```
$('#dropDown ul').append("
<li onclick=setCollege("+ data[i].id +",&quot;"+ data[i].college_name +"&quot;)><i class='fa fa-university'></i>" + data[i].college_name + "</li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation starts with double quotes(`"`). So you need to follow till the end of the statement.

Try this,

```
"'+ data[i].college_name +'"
```

instead of

```
'"+ data[i].college_name +"'
```

Also add double quotes(`" "`) surround by the onclick event, and escape them,

```
onclick=\"setcollege(.......)\"
```